# Pandas: efficient way to get a random subset from each row within a restricted column range

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have some numerical time-series of varying lengths stored in a wide pandas dataframe. Each row corresponds to one series and each column to a measurement time point. Because of their varying length, those series can have missing values (NA) tails either left (first time points) or right (last time points) or both. There is always a continuous stripe without NA of a minimum length on each row.

I need to get a random subset of fixed length from each of these rows, without including any NA. Ideally, I wish to keep the original dataframe intact and to report the subsets in a new one.

I managed to obtain this output with a very inefficient for loop that goes through each row one by one, determines a start for the crop position such that NAs will not be included in the output and copies the cropped result. This works but it is extremely slow on large datasets. Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from copy import copy

def crop_random(df_in, output_length, ignore_na_tails=True):
    # Initialize new dataframe
    colnames = ['X_' + str(i) for i in range(output_length)]
    df_crop = pd.DataFrame(index=df_in.index, columns=colnames)
    # Go through all rows
    for irow in range(df_in.shape[0]):
        series = copy(df_in.iloc[irow, :])
        series = np.array(series).astype('float')
        length = len(series)
        if ignore_na_tails:
            pos_non_na = np.where(~np.isnan(series))
            # Range where the subset might start
            lo = pos_non_na[0][0]
            hi = pos_non_na[0][-1]
            left = np.random.randint(lo, hi - output_length + 2)  
        else:
            left = np.random.randint(0, length - output_length)
        series = series[left : left + output_length]
        df_crop.iloc[irow, :] = series
    return df_crop
```

And a toy example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'t0': [np.NaN, 1, np.NaN],
                             't1': [np.NaN, 2, np.NaN],
                             't2': [np.NaN, 3, np.NaN],
                             't3': [1, 4, 1],
                             't4': [2, 5, 2],
                             't5': [3, 6, 3],
                             't6': [4, 7, np.NaN],
                             't7': [5, 8, np.NaN],
                             't8': [6, 9, np.NaN]})
#     t0   t1   t2  t3  t4  t5   t6   t7   t8
# 0  NaN  NaN  NaN   1   2   3    4    5    6
# 1    1    2    3   4   5   6    7    8    9
# 2  NaN  NaN  NaN   1   2   3  NaN  NaN  NaN

crop_random(df, 3)
# One possible output:
#    X_0  X_1  X_2
# 0    2    3    4
# 1    7    8    9
# 2    1    2    3
```

How could I achieve same results in a way adapted to large dataframes?

Edit: Moved my improved solution to the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to speed up things quite drastically with:

```py
def crop_random(dataset, output_length, ignore_na_tails=True):
    # Get a random range to crop for each row
    def get_range_crop(series, output_length, ignore_na_tails):
        series = np.array(series).astype('float')
        if ignore_na_tails:
            pos_non_na = np.where(~np.isnan(series))
            start = pos_non_na[0][0]
            end = pos_non_na[0][-1]
            left = np.random.randint(start,
                                     end - output_length + 2)  # +1 to include last in randint; +1 for slction span
        else:
            length = len(series)
            left = np.random.randint(0, length - output_length)
        right = left + output_length
        return left, right

    # Crop the rows to random range, reset_index to do concat without recreating new columns
    range_subset = dataset.apply(get_range_crop, args=(output_length,ignore_na_tails, ), axis = 1)
    new_rows = [dataset.iloc[irow, range_subset[irow][0]: range_subset[irow][1]]
                for irow in range(dataset.shape[0])]
    for row in new_rows:
        row.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    # Concatenate all rows
    dataset_cropped = pd.concat(new_rows, axis=1).T

    return dataset_cropped
```